# how can i set the key 'blob-key' about BlobStore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, uploadify, blobstore

I tried to use the jquery plugin "uploadify" to upload multiple files to My App in Google App-Engine, and then save them with blobstore, but it failed. I traced the code into get_uploads, it seems  `field.type_options` is empty, and of course does not have 'blob-key'. Where does the key 'blob-key' come from?

the code like this:

```
def upload(request):
   for blob in blogstorehelper.get_uploads(request, 'Filedata'):
       file = File()
       file.blobref = blob
       file.save()
   return ……
```

but, blogstorehelper.get_uploads(request, 'Filedata') is always empty. In fact, the request has contained the uploaded file(I print the request). I debugged into the blogstorehelper.get_uploads, and found that field.type_options is empty. who can tell me why? thank you! here is the source about get_uploads: http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/blobstore-get_uploads-helper-function-for-django-request/?id=ahJhcHBlbmdpbmUtY29va2Jvb2tyjwELEgtSZWNpcGVJbmRleCI4YWhKaGNIQmxibWRwYm1VdFkyOXZhMkp2YjJ0eUZBc1NDRU5oZEdWbmIzSjVJZ1pFYW1GdVoyOE0MCxIGUmVjaXBlIjphaEpoY0hCbGJtZHBibVV0WTI5dmEySnZiMnR5RkFzU0NFTmhkR1ZuYjNKNUlnWkVhbUZ1WjI4TTIxDA

Comment: a code sample would help people answer your question.

Comment: there is still not enough context to even know what the issue is. The example posted by Sebastián S. is quite complete, have you made sure you understand all that his code is doing? http://blog.sserrano.com/post/479962742/blobstore-upload-with-django-form-validation-example